Possibly Japanese comedy from 80s-90s, man and young boy
There was a film I saw on IFC many years ago, from Asia somewhere. It was either Chinese, Korean...probably Japanese.
It was the story of a man and this young boy who is lost, and the man tries throughout the film to get him home. The man is much older, maybe 45, and the boy is in the ~5-12 range.
I think the movie's name started with  "K", or maybe that was the main character's name. It was kind of a quirky comedy, with the man encountering oddball characters, all while "protecting" this boy in a way.
There was specific scene where a man they encounter asks the main character to wear a diaper of some sort. The last shot of the film is the man walking across a concrete foot bridge. I think.

Actually, I think I might be looking for Kikujiro (1999).


Kikujiro tells the story of a young boy searching for his mother during his summer vacation. The film is mostly divided into smaller chapters, listed as entries in the boy's summer vacation diary.





https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jviic-JBpSc One of Takeshi's bests.
